# Creating vector from c-array

Tags: c++

Trying to make vector from **part**(5 elements) of c-array.

```
const static int size = 10;
cout << "vector from C-array: " << endl;
int ia[size] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
vector<int> vi2(ia, ia + size-5);
```

But when I try enumerate vector items using whole length of c-array I got all items like vector would be initialized like `vector<int> vi2(ia, ia + size-5);` . No exception or error that it goes out of range.

```
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    cout << i << ":" << vi2[i] << " ";
}
```

In output:

```
0:1 1:2 2:3 3:4 4:5 5:6 6:7 7:8 8:9 9:10
```

Why vector initialization is using second param that describes pointer to array end if it doesn't uses it?

Comment: Have you checked `vi2.size()`? It should give `5`, and if it does, accessing beyond the 5th element will give you undefined behaviour.

Comment: `vi2` _is_ using that end of array pointer. _You_ are the one who is ignoring it and indexing it all the way to `size`.

Comment: If you want an exception to be thrown, use `vector<T>::at()` instead of `vector<T>::operator[]`.\

Comment: The output shown is *possible*, like it's possible to get an asteroid in the head. It is however just as unlikely. Can you post a **complete but minimal** example that exhibits the claimed behavior.

Comment: BTW: If you want five elements, write `vector<int> vi2(ia, ia + 5);` instead of `vector<int> vi2(ia, ia + size-5);`. In this case, it doesn't matter, because size-5 == 5, but the first way indicates that you want the first five, and the second indicates you want all but the last five.

Answer (score 3):

You are accessing your vector out of bounds. This is *undefined behaviour*. There is no requirement that an exception be thrown.

You must not go beyond `vi2.size()-1`.

```
for(int i = 0; i < vi2.size(); ++i) 
{
  std::cout << i << ":" << vi2[i] << " ";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `[]` operator doesn't do any bounds checking (similarly to the `[]` operator in C and C++ which works with raw arrays).

If you want an exception to be thrown, then use the `at` member function:

```
std::vector<int> v { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
int invalidInt = v.at(5); // hell breaks lose, says the runtime
```

Answer (score 1):

C++ doesn't throw an exception the way Java does if you access an out of bounds index. It's [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367633/what-are-all-the-common-undefined-behaviour-that-a-c-programmer-should-know-ab), and you simply must not do it.

```
for(int i = 0; i < vi2.size(); i++) {
    cout << i << ":" << vi2[i] << " ";
}
```

See [A Guide to Undefined Behavior in C and C++](http://blog.regehr.org/archives/213):

> In a *safe* programming language, errors are trapped as they happen. Java, for example, is largely safe via its exception system. In an *unsafe* programming language, errors are not trapped. Rather, after executing an erroneous operation the program keeps going, but in a silently faulty way that may have observable consequences later on.

Comment: Agree regarding exception, but vector initialization looks still stupid for me. Why C++ needs to copy whole array in to vector instead copying just 5 elements

Comment: It doesn't. I doubt most compilers do that, since it's so inefficient.

Comment: @user1501700 it only copies 5 elements.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want an exception to be thrown when you're out of bounds, use `.at()`:

```
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    cout << i << ":" << vi2.at(i) << " ";
}
```

That being said, better use the actual size of `vi2` (`vi2.size()`) instead.